# Is there a greeting used on war memorial/returned services days such as ANZAC Day or Veteran's Day?

Tags: greetings

Today is ANZAC day in New Zealand, which commemorates those who served and died in WWI and WWII.

I'm wondering if there is a common greeting people use on such days, similar to how we have 'Merry Christmas', 'Happy New Year', 'Happy Birthday'.

Obviously war memorials tend to me more somber, so 'Happy' probably isn't appropriate.

Comment: I've never heard of anything of this nature in the US.  If there is something (in the US) it would likely be a ritual of the military services, vs a general greeting that everyone knows/does.  (What they do in kiwi land I can't guess.)

Comment: Thank you for asking this. I am also looking for the correct statement to greet my friends in Aussie and NZ on ANZAC day

Answer (score 1):

I believe the salutation you're looking for is "lest we forget." This phrase is used in Return Service League clubs across Australia (the 'A' part of ANZAC) when referring to those who served in First and Second World Wars. Though used generally, it's particularly common on ANZAC Day.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lest_we_forget

Answer (score 0):

**We will remember them.** Not really a greeting but it reflects a shared sentiment.

At Remembrance Day in Canada (November 11) in addition to the noted "Lest We Forget", probably in use throughout the Commonwealth, a stanza from the poem by Lawrence Binyon always forms a part of what is a solemn public observation:

"They shall not grow old, as we that are left grow old; Age shall not
weary them, nor the years condemn. At the going down of the sun and in
the morning, We will remember them"

http://www.greatwar.co.uk/poems/laurence-binyon-for-the-fallen.htm

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ode_of_Remembrance